# Open and closed sets in metric spaces: Is my reasoning correct?

Tags: solution-verification, metric-spaces

I'm learning about metric spaces. I'm working on this problem, and I sort of think I start to get it. I Would be very happy I someone would check if my reasoning is correct.

The problem:

Let $A = \mathbb{R} \setminus [-1,1] = (- \infty, -1) \bigcup \;(1, \infty) $

My reasoning:

1. I visulize $\mathbb{R}$ as a simple number line
2. [-1, 1] is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ because it contains all its boundary points.
3. The compliment of [-1, 1] is "the rest" of $\mathbb{R}$
4. The compliment of [-1, 1] is open because [-1, 1] is closed

So in conclusion A is open.

Comment: How would you define boundary point without introducing open sets?

Comment: This is sound reasoning. You could also think about it like $ \left( -\infty, -1 \right) \cup \left(1, \infty \right)$ is the union of two open sets so is open.

Comment: You might also note that each open ray has no boundary at all. The union of a finite number of open sets is also open

Comment: The union of *any collection* of open sets is also open.  It doesn't have to be finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is arguably correct, but I'd be careful about the statement "$[-1, 1]$ is closed in $\mathbb R$ because it contains all its boundary points", since this requires a proof (which you don't provide) more complicated than the original problem.

It's much easier to just point out that $A$ is the union of two open intervals, hence it is open.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: I think the question is alright